# Simple regular expression matching using LaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex, l3regex

I would like to do some simple pattern matching in LaTeX, where a character in the pattern (e.g., shell like as in `*`, or regex like as in `.*`, I´ll use the latter) replaces zero or more characters in the target.  I have strong a preference for a solution that works seamlessly with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX and luaLaTeX.

Given a list of lists and a pattern, like:

```latex
\newcommand{\target}{{a,b,c},{a,x,y,c},{a,b,d}}
\newcommand{\pattern}{a,.*,c}
```

I would like to have a command

```latex
\matchpattern{\pattern}{\target}\result
```

that would set `\result` to the elements in `\target` matching `\pattern`, i.e.,

```latex
{{a,b,c},{a,x,y,c}}
```

I'm also ok with `\result` ending with only the first `{a,b,c}` or last `{a,x,y,c}` match (and not all the matches), if it makes the solution simpler/easier.

I believe that both the package `makematch` and `l3regex` could help. But I could not understand how to use `makematch` from the documentation, and `l3regex` if far beyond my wizard level.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: you could use l3regexp for that but do you really want to use regular expressions here (slow and delicate) it would be much quicler for this case for eample to consider the target as clists (comma lists) and accept all such lists that have first entry  `a`  and last entry `c` it would aslo save asking if you want `za,zb,zc` to match since it matches ``a.*c``

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for the suggestion.  I don't need really need a regex, and I could do with a simpler solution.  Although for clarity my example omits it, the "*" operator may be in the beginning, middle or end of the pattern. The pattern may even have no star operator.  Do you believe that, in this case, the list processing approach is still going to be faster than a regex?

Comment: Are you familiar with Lua and its pattern-matching functions? If so, you could easily perform pattern matching while compiling your LaTeX document with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is

```
\matchpattern[+][*]{<pattern>}{<target>}<result>
```

where `+` denotes using a stored pattern and `*` using a stored target.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\matchpattern}{t+ s m m m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% use stored pattern
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}
     {% expand the argument
      \joao_matchpattern:nVNN #3 #4 #5 \regex_match:NnT
     }
     {% explicit argument
      \joao_matchpattern:nnNN #3 { #4 } #5 \regex_match:NnT
     }
   }
   {% use explicit pattern
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}
     {% expand the argument
      \joao_matchpattern:nVNN { #3 } #4 #5 \regex_match:nnT
     }
     {
      \joao_matchpattern:nnNN { #3 } { #4 } #5 \regex_match:nnT
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definepattern}{mm}
 {
  \regex_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }

\clist_new:N \l__joao_matchpattern_tmp_clist

\cs_new_protected:Nn \joao_matchpattern:nnNN
 {% #4 is either \regex_match:NnT or \regex_match:nnT
  % #1 is the pattern (either stored or explicit)
  % #2 is the target (either stored or explicit)
  % #3 is the macro to hold the result
  \clist_clear:N \l__joao_matchpattern_tmp_clist  
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    #4 { #1 } { ##1 }
     {
      \clist_put_right:Nn \l__joao_matchpattern_tmp_clist { {##1} }
     }
   }
  \clist_set_eq:NN #3 \l__joao_matchpattern_tmp_clist
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \joao_matchpattern:nnNN { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\matchpattern{a,.*,c}{{a,b,c},{a,x,y,c},{a,b,d}}\result

\show\result

\definepattern{\pattern}{a,.*,c}

\matchpattern+{\pattern}{{a,b,c},{a,x,y,c},{a,b,d}}\result

\show\result

\newcommand{\target}{{a,b,c},{a,x,y,c},{a,b,d}}

\matchpattern+*{\pattern}{\target}\result

\show\result

\stop
```

In all three cases the answer is

```
> \result=macro:
->{a,b,c},{a,x,y,c}.
```

Comment: Thanks egreg. I definitely need to upgrade my wizard skills to latex3. :)